# Show confirmation box depending on a hidden field value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, bootstrap-4

So a bit of background, I basically have a form where users can change stuff. This form is a bootstrap modal form. I want to display a warning or something when users close the form down if they have made changes to the form. So I thought I would add a hidden field and when things changes on the form (multiple ways this can happen) then I will mark the hidden field with a true value.

I have this working but now all that is left is to create something that will look at the hidden value then show a confirmation box to say something in the realm of "You have made changes and will loose all changes you have made. Would you like to continue?" with a yes, no or ok, cancel buttons.

I though this would be rather simple but for some reason I am struggling and I am not sure why.

My button is create like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnX" runat="server" CssClass="close" Text="&times;" OnClientClick="return confirmClick();" />
```

I have a server onclick function done in vb.net/c# language is no issue for me I can always translate it like this

```
Public Sub btnX_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnX.Click
   CloseModalForm()
 End Sub
```

I also have javascript which would ideally call before the server code

```
function confirmClick() {
            var _changed = document.getElementById('<%=hiddenField.ClientID %>').value;
            if (_changed == true) {
                alert(_changed);
            }
        }
```

However this does not work, I know this is an alert box, I ended up changing it to an alert while trying to get this to work and seeing if i could get a popup message to say true when hidden field is true and for it not to appear when the hidden field is false. I have messed around a lot on this hence why i ended up with alert. But nothing seems to work if i try just

```
if (alert(_changed)) {
  alert(_changed);
}
```

Then it shows the alert box regardless if the value is a true or false

This seems very simple to me, but I cannot get it to work, which must mean I am missing something which I have not thought about. I have googled how to do if statements with Booleans in case I got that wrong but I cannot see anything wrong in what I am doing. The only other thing is maybe I have completely negated something or miss interpreted the way JS works. Ideally this would be client side rather than server side as this is just a case of asking users if they want to continue. I still need the server side procedure as many more things happen while the modal form closes down.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first, I assume you have some kind of dialog system you are using. You can try to use bootstrap ones, but they look fantatic, but the markup and really easy way to pop such a dialog with code beyond sucks. So, I suggest using jQuery.UI dialogs. (only issue with jQuery.UI dialogs is the don't look all that great. But, for this example, that's what we going to use.

next up:
We all know that when you drop in a server side button, you can can ALSO add that client side click, and if the routine returns true, then server side click code behind will run. if the js routine returns false, then the server side click button code does not run. This is rather clear, and even your posted code shows this knowledge.

so, for super quick and dirty, and in a hurry, we can, and often do this:

```
        <asp:Button id="cmdDelete2" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left:15px"
            type="button"
            onclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick"
            onclientclick="return confirm('Really delete?')"  >
        </asp:Button>
```

Of course for above, we get/see the web browser dialog, and those look REALLY poor!

but, it does work. And thus you get this:
(I am editing a single record in a popup dialog in above)

[image]

So, the above use of js confirm() will work. But as you can see, the position and how ugly that dialog box is? Well, its just ugly.

so, we can adopt jQuery.UI dialog. They are much better looking. Of course there are bootstrap ones, and I see quite a few people using sweetAlert (very very nice).

Anyway, ONE BIG HUGE issue with all of these so called "dialog" libraries that look great, function great, and even allow you to set the position of the dialog?

Well, first lets change above to use a jQuery.UI dialog (and I show how in a bit).

So, that rather ugly built in browser dialog now becomes this:

[image]

The above is now much nicer. And even better is when you click on that button, the dialog pops RIGHT below and to the right of the dialog.(where you eyes are current looking since you just looked to click on that button!

You can try the above and play with a working demo here:
(it is vb.net + web forms).

Ok, so the next issue to tackle?

All of the current JavaScript (js) frameworks operation on NON BLOCKING code! That means that while confirm() does halt the code, does wait, and then continue when you hit ok (or cancel)? Such blocking code, or halt js code is not allowed anymore. About the only exception is alert() and confirm(). But, they can lock up and freeze the browser code, so they are not recommended anymore.
So, all such 3rd party - and even in the future? Non blocking code is to be used. That means the code is asynchronous.

so, if we call code to pop a dialog? The function will run, display the dialog AND THEN RETURN and EXIT!!!!

but now, that means we can't wait to return the true/false value to the button click (client side).

But, you can use a neat-o little trick!!!

You now (have to) do this:

You run the client side code - return false (server side button click does not run). then when the user makes their choice in the pop dialog, you then set a flag to return true and CLICK the button again!!! This time, the client side routine fires again, but returns true (assuming you hit ok!!!).

So, the code will look like this:

The button looks like this:

```
        <button id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left:15px"
            type="button"
            onserverclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick"
            onclick="if (!MyConfirmDel(this)) {return false};"  >
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</span>
        </button>
```

Note in above, I did not use a asp:Button, since I wanted the fancy looking bootstrap icon in the button (trash). But, how this works for a button, or asp.net button is the same. But I had to change the comfirm routine a bit, and use the above !MyConfirmDel(this) (the button combines both onclick and onserverclick - and they actually run as one js routine - we can't change that. If you using plain jane asp.net button, then the first markup will work the same.

and the js code now looks like this:

```
      var MyConfirmDelOK = false
       function MyConfirmDel(Btn) {
           if (MyConfirmDelOK) {
               MyConfirmDelOK = false
               return true
           }
           var myDialog = $("#mydelpop");
           myDialog.dialog({
               title: "Delete Hotel",
               width: "26em",
               modal: true,
               dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow',                   
               position: { my: "left top", at: "right bottom", of: Btn },
                buttons: {
                    Delete: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog('close')
                        MyConfirmDelOK= true
                        $(Btn).click()
                    },
                    cancel: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog('close')
                    }
                }
           });
```

Note careful in above. We passed the button, pop the dialog. User makes choice from dialog, and if ok/yes clicked, we set flag = true, and THEN click the button again. The button click runs the client side code again, but this time, it returns true, and thus the server side click code will now run.

If you are using a plain jane asp.net, then this:

```
        <asp:Button id="cmdDelete2" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left:15px"
            type="button"
            onclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick"
            OnClientClick="return MyConfirmDel(this)"  >
        </asp:Button>
```

You can try and play with a working demo here for above:

http://www.kallal.ca/WebSite11/WebForm2

Your next idea?

I want to "confirm" or "warn" or have some dialog if they actually changed things?
Don't!!! - just don't!!! If you do that, then EVERY place where you have edits, then for the sake of a consistant UI experiance, then you have to do that.
And it just becomes a "nag" for the users. (and you going to have to write quite a bit of extra client side code to make this work). When you pop a dialog, give them a save button, and a cancel button. Users will then make a habit of hitting the cancel button to go back. They will not care if they accident edit, since they can learn to always hit cancel if they did not mean to edit.

(you can see this UI in action in the above link).

You can have such a confirm dialog - but the less dialogs, the more enjoyable the software becomes. Give the users a cancel or un-do button. Let them decide if they want to bail out - not nag them  all day long.

Comment: ok so my issue mainly relates to calling a js confirm box depending on other things on the form. I do not want the confirm box to appear all the time. Only when something is set on the page. As for look and feel, yes its not the best looking but this is for a separate page within our app which will look and feel different so I am not averse to changing things. I will definitely look at jquery to make it look nice and possibly have it so they can choose to save or cancel. However my problem will still exist. I would only want the box to appear on certain situations.

Comment: Ok, so you need to wire up a onchange event to each text box. That little js routine thus can set a flag in that hidden field. Then in the code that supposed to pop the dialog, it can make a decision based on that hidden field flag.

Comment: Not sure if you have realised but that is where I have the problem. I have a hidden field in the form and via js it is setting it on the situation I want it to be. The issue I face is showing the confirmation box using the hidden field. Please see original post which shows the js I have been using which clearly shows i only want the confirmation box based on the hidden field. This however I cannot get working for some reason.